# How to unit test subfunctions in QUnit?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sapui5, qunit

I have the following code in my SAPUI5 app.

This function is trigger when a button is clicked.

```
onClear(oEvent){
   var source = oEvent.getSource().getText(); //get the text on the button
   ....
 }
```

In my Unit test I have

```
QUnit.module('onClear functio test);
  Qunit.test('onClear press test', function(assert){
     var getSource = sinon.spy();
      var getText = sinon.spy();

     var oEvent = {getSsource: getSource};
     var source = "Clear"; //this is what should be return for this test

   //call the function
    mainController.onClear(oEvent, source); 
 }
```

The error I get is `"Unable to get property 'getText' of undefined or null reference"`

From SAP API, `oEvent.getSource()` simply returns a reference to the object triggering the event, in this case a button. During the testing `.getSource()` doesn't return anything I believe.
So how can make this work? I know I can break down my code into 2 different lines and spy/stub those 2 functions separately but I don't want to do that as the code I have is valid JavaScript code.

Comment: You must accept scope[1](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) [2](https://toddmotto.com/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-javascript-scope/). Refactoring would be needed.

Comment: I don't understand what scope has to do in this case?

Comment: `mainController.onClear(oEvent, source)` will not set `var source` in `onClear(oEvent)`

Comment: I see what you mean. I was passing extra variables before but wasn't doing anything with them, hence I thought that was working. Is there a way to make chaining functions work in QUnit? It seems be a major problem I've encountered with this tool.

Comment: Not that I am aware. That's one reason I like [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/): it helps to enforce [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) design to support testing.